# Can I compare the current value with previous value in a while loop?

Tags: matlab, while-loop

I use a `while` loop to move the random points each one second as a shot from position to position. Now, how can I compare `sigdB` as calculated in the current step with `sigdB` from the previous step?

```
npts=1;center=[0 0];radius=1000; npts2=1;center2=[0 0];radius2=1000;
velocity = 45/3.6; velocity2 = 45/3.6;
theta = rand(npts, 1) * 2*pi;
g = 0.5 * radius + 0.5 * radius * rand(npts,1);
X_x=center(1)+g.*cos(theta); Y_y=center(2)+g.*sin(theta); XY = [X_x ,Y_y];
theta2 = rand(npts2, 1) * 2*pi; g2 = 0.5 * radius2 + 0.5 * radius2 * rand(npts2,1);
X_x2=center2(1)+g2.*cos(theta2); Y_y2=center2(2)+g.*sin(theta2); XY2 = [X_x2 ,Y_y2];
hfig = figure('Color', 'w'); hax = axes('Parent', hfig);
hdots(1) = plot(XY(1,1),XY(1,2),'Parent', hax,'Marker', '.','Color', 'k','LineStyle', 'none','MarkerSize', 10); hold(hax, 'on'); axis(hax, 'equal');

hdots(2) = plot(XY2(1,1),XY2(1,2),'Parent', hax,'Marker', '.','Color', 'r','LineStyle', 'none','MarkerSize', 10); hold(hax, 'on'); axis(hax, 'equal');
% plot circle to scatter the points in it
t = linspace(0, 2*pi, 100); plot(radius * cos(t) + center(1),radius * sin(t) + center(2))

while all(ishghandle(hdots))
distPoints = pdist2(XY,XY2,'euclidean'); 
sig=sum(power*(distPoints).^-2);
sigdB=10*log(sig);
direction2 = rand(npts, 1) * 2 *pi;  direction = rand(npts, 1) * 2 *pi;

    [XY2, direction2] = step(XY2, direction2, velocity2, radius2, center2); [XY, direction] = step(XY, direction, velocity, radius, center);

    set(hdots(2), 'XData', XY2(1,1), 'YData', XY2(1,2)); set(hdots(1), 'XData', XY(1,1), 'YData', XY(1,2)); drawnow; pause (1);
end
```

Answer (score 3):

The moment you call `sigdB = (..)` you overwrite its previous value. If you want to compare *only* the previous one, you could use a simple trick to store it separately:

```
while
    sigdB_old = sigdB;
    sigdB = 10*log(..);
    % More calculations
end
```

i.e. store it in a temporary variable. If, on the other hand, you want to retain *all* previous values, you should store it in an array of appropriate size, if possible. This is usually easier in a `for` loop, given you know how many iterations will take place, but you could simply initialise your array "pretty large" and extend or cut-off rows/columns where needed.